# 'Undo' the effect of one number from an arithmetic mean?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, average

I have a computer program that finds the arithmetic mean of 9 numbers. Sometimes, though, it needs to eliminate some of those numbers from consideration - in other words I actually need it to actually find the average of a set of 1-8 numbers that is a subset of those 9.

It'd make my program significantly slower and more complicated to have it notice that it needs to do so and adjust the summing and dividing accordingly; it'd be better to have it always sum 9 numbers and divide by 9.

This is kind of a long shot, but I thought I'd ask: is there any simple way to take that average and "remove" one of the numbers from it, or is there a value such that if N of the 9 values is that value then the average of the set will equal the average of the set minus those numbers?

Comment: Say the current average is $A$, and you want to remove value $n$.  The new average is $\frac{9}{8}(A - \frac{n}{9})$.

Comment: @ChocolateAndCheese That's assuming you know the value of the number your removing. On the other hand, if you don't know it, you're out of luck.

Comment: @ChocolateAndCheese The trouble with that is that I need to know `n` and `A` at the same time to do that, which makes it impossible to do the elimination "ahead of time" once so that I don't have to do extra work when I'm actually computing the averages. I *suspect* there's no way to actually do that frontloading, but I thought I'd ask anyway.

Comment: @Schilcote Hmm, maybe I'm misunderstanding.  You have values $\{n_0, ..., n_8\}$ that have average $A$.  You will possibly drop a subset of those values, and you want to compute the new average?  In that case all I can think of is precomputing the average for each subset of the original 9 values.  $2^9 = 512$ distinct subsets is computationally feasible, although I can hardly imagine a situation where this approach would be useful.

Comment: @ChocolateAndCheese Yeah, the overhead of branching is _probably_ less than that. :P

Comment: @Schilcote Basically, if you don't know the values you are trying to average, you will not be able to compute an average.  You could compute the "average average" of each subset or something, but this would not be an exact answer.  Why is it so complicated to compute the average at runtime using the formula I wrote down in my previous comment?

Comment: It's not, it's just that it's even less complicated to just check for each of the 9 numbers if I actually want to include it in the average, when I actually do the averaging. I was just wondering if, given that I'll know whether or not I want to include a large number of those values long before I know what the actual value of the value is, I can figure out which values I don't want to include ahead of time.

Comment: What I'm actually doing is a rudimentary simulation of a scent dispersing in air, where the level of a scent is a real in a 2D array and the scent level at a position one tick from now is the average of the scent level at that and all adjacent positions where there is no solid object. I was hoping I could build an "obstructedness mask" once and then overlay it on each scent level array somehow, thus eliminating 8 branch conditions for every position in the world times every scent-emitting object in the simulation - which would *probably* result in a big speedup!

Comment: @Schilcote - sounds like an interesting simulation! would be in any way related to the movement of stock prices over time?

Comment: @hypergeometric Not that I know of.